# Why is a subscript producing an undesirable effect with my circle command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have this circled command defined which just circles the given parameter. Here's how I have it defined:

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[anchor=text, shape=circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.2em] (char) {#1\strut};}}
```

It almost always works how I want it to work. For example, this code

```
\circled{z=2}\implies1\cdot y-2(2)=2\implies \circled{y=6}\implies x-3(6)+6(2)=-1\implies \circled{x=5}
```

Gives me this:

[image]

However, whenever I try to circle something with subscripts, it all goes haywire. For example, this code

```
-35x_3=-35\implies\circled{x_3=1}\implies-10x_2-15=5\implies\circled{x_2=-2}
```

Gives me this:

[image]

As you can see, it messes up the next bulleted item as well. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document (as you can see in examples below), which we can compile as it is and which reproduce your problem.
- Source of your problems is content of `\circled` command, which is not in math node. This you can assure on two ways:

  - redefine `\newcommand` as follows:

  ```
  \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[anchor=text, shape=circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.2em] (char) {$#1\strut$};}}
  ```

  and use your code fragment as they are

  - left definition for `\circled` command as it is and insert `$` around content of `\circled` command in test code fragment.

First example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[anchor=text, shape=circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.2em] (char) {$#1\strut$};}}

\begin{document}
$-35x_3=-35\implies\circled{x_3=1}\implies-10x_2-15=5\implies\circled{x_2=-2}$
\end{document}
```

Second example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[anchor=text, shape=circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2.2em] (char) {#1\strut};}}

\begin{document}
$-35x_3=-35\implies\circled{$x_3=1$}\implies-10x_2-15=5\implies\circled{$x_2=-2$}$
\end{document}
```

In both cases the result is the same:

[image]